# Why need to tune lambda with caret::train(..., method = "glmnet") and cv.glmnet()?

Tags: r, glmnet

As we can see that `caret::train(..., method = "glmnet")` with cross-validation or `cv.glmnet()` implemented both could find the `lambda.min` which minimize the cross-validation error. The final best fitted model should be the one fitted with `lambda.min`. Then, why do we need to set a grid of `lambda` values to the training process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We use a custom tuning grid for a `glmnet` model, because the default tuning grid is very small and there are many more potential `glmnet` models we may want to explore.

`glmnet` is capable of fitting 2 different kinds of penalized models, and it has 2 tuning parameters:

1. **alpha**

   - Ridge regression (or alpha = 0)
   - Lasso regression (or alpha = 1)
2. **lambda**

   - the strength of the penalty on the coefficients

The `glmnet` model can fit many models at once (for single `alpha`, all values of `lambda` fit simultaneously), we can pass a large number of `lambda` values which control the amount of penalization in the model.

`train()` is smart enough to only fit one model per `alpha` value and pass all of the `lambda` values at one for simultaneous fitting.

Example:

```
# Make a custom tuning grid
tuneGrid <- expand.grid(alpha = 0:1, lambda = seq(0.0001, 1, length = 10))

# Fit a model
model <- train(y ~ ., overfit, method = "glmnet",
  tuneGrid = tuneGrid, trControl = myControl
)


# Sample Output
Warning message: The metric "Accuracy" was not in the result set. ROC will be used instead.
+ Fold01: alpha=0, lambda=1 
- Fold01: alpha=0, lambda=1 
+ Fold01: alpha=1, lambda=1 
- Fold01: alpha=1, lambda=1 
+ Fold02: alpha=0, lambda=1 
- Fold02: alpha=0, lambda=1 
+ Fold02: alpha=1, lambda=1 
- Fold02: alpha=1, lambda=1 
+ Fold03: alpha=0, lambda=1 
- Fold03: alpha=0, lambda=1 
+ Fold03: alpha=1, lambda=1 
- Fold03: alpha=1, lambda=1 
+ Fold04: alpha=0, lambda=1 
- Fold04: alpha=0, lambda=1 
+ Fold04: alpha=1, lambda=1 
- Fold04: alpha=1, lambda=1 
+ Fold05: alpha=0, lambda=1 
- Fold05: alpha=0, lambda=1 
+ Fold05: alpha=1, lambda=1 
- Fold05: alpha=1, lambda=1 
+ Fold06: alpha=0, lambda=1 
- Fold06: alpha=0, lambda=1 
+ Fold06: alpha=1, lambda=1 
- Fold06: alpha=1, lambda=1 
+ Fold07: alpha=0, lambda=1 
- Fold07: alpha=0, lambda=1 
+ Fold07: alpha=1, lambda=1 
- Fold07: alpha=1, lambda=1 
+ Fold08: alpha=0, lambda=1 
- Fold08: alpha=0, lambda=1 
+ Fold08: alpha=1, lambda=1 
- Fold08: alpha=1, lambda=1 
+ Fold09: alpha=0, lambda=1 
- Fold09: alpha=0, lambda=1 
+ Fold09: alpha=1, lambda=1 
- Fold09: alpha=1, lambda=1 
+ Fold10: alpha=0, lambda=1 
- Fold10: alpha=0, lambda=1 
+ Fold10: alpha=1, lambda=1 
- Fold10: alpha=1, lambda=1 
Aggregating results
Selecting tuning parameters
Fitting alpha = 1, lambda = 1 on full training set


# Print model to console
model


# Sample Output
glmnet 

250 samples
200 predictors
  2 classes: 'class1', 'class2' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold) 
Summary of sample sizes: 225, 225, 225, 225, 224, 226, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  alpha  lambda  ROC        Sens  Spec     
  0      0.0001  0.3877717  0.00  0.9786232
  0      0.1112  0.4352355  0.00  1.0000000
  0      0.2223  0.4546196  0.00  1.0000000
  0      0.3334  0.4589674  0.00  1.0000000
  0      0.4445  0.4718297  0.00  1.0000000
  0      0.5556  0.4762681  0.00  1.0000000
  0      0.6667  0.4783514  0.00  1.0000000
  0      0.7778  0.4826087  0.00  1.0000000
  0      0.8889  0.4869565  0.00  1.0000000
  0      1.0000  0.4869565  0.00  1.0000000
  1      0.0001  0.3368659  0.05  0.9188406
  1      0.1112  0.5000000  0.00  1.0000000
  1      0.2223  0.5000000  0.00  1.0000000
  1      0.3334  0.5000000  0.00  1.0000000
  1      0.4445  0.5000000  0.00  1.0000000
  1      0.5556  0.5000000  0.00  1.0000000
  1      0.6667  0.5000000  0.00  1.0000000
  1      0.7778  0.5000000  0.00  1.0000000
  1      0.8889  0.5000000  0.00  1.0000000
  1      1.0000  0.5000000  0.00  1.0000000

ROC was used to select the optimal model using  the largest value.
The final values used for the model were alpha = 1 and lambda = 1.


# Plot model
plot(model)
```

[image]

Comment: @Levande  I didn't know that you could use glmnet for both `ridge regression` and `lasso`! Thank you